# How can I access an xsl:variable from outside the "scope" of an xsl:for-each block

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to access a variable from within a for-each. I've done a lot of reading today to try to figure this out, but nothing quite fits my scenario. Eventually, I will have multiple series like seen below and I will use the variables that I'm pulling out and make different condition. The for-each that I have below is bringing back data from 400 records. I'm sorry, I cannot provide an XML. I'm not able to expose GUIDs and such.

**UPDATE**

```
       <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output media-type="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Records>
      <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record/Record[@levelGuid = 'level1']">
        <xsl:variable name="rocName1" select="Field[@guid = '123']"/>
        <xsl:variable name ="rocName2" select="substring-before($rocName1, ' - ')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>


      <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record/Record[@levelGuid = 'levelA']">
        <xsl:variable name ="findingName" select="Field[@guid = '123']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="findingName1" select="substring-after($findingName, ': ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="findingName2" select="substring-after($findingName1, 'PCIDSSv3.1:')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:if test="$findingName1 = $rocName1">
        <Records>
          <findingID>
            <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record/Record[@levelGuid = '123']">
              <xsl:value-of select ="Field[@guid = '123']"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </findingID>
        </Records>
      </xsl:if>
  </Records>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The desired output is any findingID that has a $findingName1 that equals $rocName1. The GUIDS only appear once, but each level has hundreds of records.

Comment: "*The desired output is any findingID that has a $findingName1 that equals $rocName1.*"That really doesn't mean much and your code - which doesn't work - is not helping either. Please post an example XML input, explain in a few words the logic of the requested transformation, and show us  the expected output.

Comment: I know you are starting out to learn XSLT, and you have trouble grasping the concepts, so I have taken your code, with some assumptions, and showed you how what you want to achieve (get data from a sibling node while on another node) can be achieved quite easily. Take some time to get to know and understand the code, together with some hands-on tutorials on the net.

Comment: I inserted the real GUIDs for the dumby GUIDs and it didn't return any output. The path to the data is "Records/Record/Record[@levelGuid = '123']/Field[@guid = '123']". So I was using a for-each so that it would loop through all of the records. If the template is applied then doesn't that mean that it is making the second application do this: "Records/Record/Record[@levelGuid = '123']/"Records/Record/Record[@levelGuid = '123']. This would not access the correct information

Comment: Your question consists largely of code that doesn't work, plus a statement that you want to write the code in a particular way. This is no way to pose a question: we can't be expected to work out from non-working code what problem you are trying to solve. The most we can say is that you are going about it the wrong way, and if you tell us more about your problem, then we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to access a variable from within a for-each.

The variable `$rocRecord` is in scope inside the for-each. You can simply reference it and use it.

But I think you are trying to do something else. I.e., defining a variable *inside* for-each and wanting to use it *outside* it.

Variables are scoped within their focus-setting containing block. So the short answer is: you cannot do it. The long answer however...

Use templates. The only reason to do what you seem to want to be doing is to need to access the data elsewhere:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- in fact, you don't need for-each at all, but I leave it in for clarity -->
    <xsl:for-each select="records/record">

        <!-- 
            apply-templates means: call the declared xsl:template that 
            matches this node, it is somewhat similar to a function call in other 
            languages, except that it works the other way around, the processor will 
            magically find the "function" (i.e., template) for you 
        -->

        <xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@guid='123']" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Field">
    <!-- the focus here is what is the contents of your variable $rocName1 -->
    <rocName>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring=-before(., ' - ')" />
    </rocName>
</xsl:template>
```

XSLT is a declarative, template-oriented, functional language with concepts that are quite unique compared to most other languages. It can take a few hours to get used to it.

You said you did a lot of reading, but perhaps it is time to check a little XSLT course? There are a few online, search for "XSLT fundamentals course". It will save you hours / days of frustration.

This is a good, short read [to catch up on variables in XSLT](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xslt/ch04_05.htm).

### Update

On second read, I think it looks like you are troubled by the fact that the loop goes on for 400 items and that you only want to output the value of `$rocName1`. The example I showed above, does exactly that, **because apply-templates does nothing if the selection is empty**, which is what happens if the guid is not found.

If the guid appears once, the code above will output it once. If it appears multiple times and you only want the first, append `[1]` to the select statement.

### Update #2 (after your update with an example)

You have two loops:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Records/Record/Record[@levelGuid = 'level1']">
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="Records/Record/Record[@levelGuid = 'levelA']">
```

You then want to do something (created a `findingId`) when a record in the first loop matches a record in the second loop.

While you *can* solve this using (nested) loops, it is not necessary to do so, in fact, it is discouraged as it will make your code hard to read. As I explained in my original answer, apply-templates is usually the easier way to do get this to work.

Since the `Record` elements are siblings of one another, I would tackle this as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Records>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Records/Records/Record[@levelGuid = 'level1']" />
    </Records>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:variable name="rocName1" select="Field[@guid = '123']"/>
    <xsl:variable name ="rocName2" select="substring-before($rocName1, ' - ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="findingNameBase" select="../Record[@levelGuid = 'levelA']" />
    <xsl:variable name ="findingName" select="$findingNameBase/Field[@guid = '123']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="findingName1" select="substring-after($findingName, ': ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="findingName2" select="substring-after($findingName1, 'PCIDSSv3.1:')"/>
    <findingId rocName="{$rocName1}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$findingName" />
    </findingId>
</xsl:template>
```

While this can be simplified further, it is a good start to learn about applying templates, which is at the core of anything you do with XSLT. [Learn about applying templates](http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/), because without it, XSLT will be very hard to understand.

Comment: @dontchucknorris Please, do not paste (large) code chunks in comments. You can [edit] your original question. Btw, the only difference is with the `$rocName2` variable being used outside the for-each, which is exactly what I assumed in (the rest of) my answer.

Comment: @dontchucknorris, I updated the answer, perhaps this makes it a bit clearer. Though you didn't state in your question what you were trying to achieve, I have tried to understand it from the context.

Comment: I will end up creating a similar block of code for a different level. Then I will say if $rocName1 = $var2 then do this. I'm required to say for-each so that it returns a field value for each individual record. The Records/Record/Record[guid] is the path to the application that I am pulling from. However, then I have to pull from a 2nd application with Records/Record/Record[differentguid]. At this point, I want to compare the values in 1 application to the values in a second application.

Comment: @dontchucknorris, XSLT works in a different way and any level of any part of your input (or another input doc for that matter) can typically be accessed from any part of your code. There's no need to carry variables around to do what you want. Consider [asking another q.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a simple test input doc that exemplifies what you are trying to achieve and we'll try to help you further. From the description you give, this appears a trivial task in XSLT, but without input, expected output etc there's not much I can help you further with...

Comment: I made an update to the original question. Please let me know if that makes more sense. I appreciate the help!